# Generate the maven artifact path

Tags: maven

Maven install knows all the artifacts generated by a build, and will push them locally.

> Installs the project's main artifact, and any other artifacts attached by other plugins in the lifecycle, to the local repository.

the help plugin probably supports this, but not sure of right expression

```
# has all the pieces (artifact, version, type) but is it fair to assume filename will always be that combo?
mvn help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.artifact
```

Is there any way to get that list of paths from a maven command?

I want to generate a list of specific artifacts to persist as artifact results in a build process, without publishing to a maven repo.

Comment: Why persist them in the build process? What is the idea? Or what kind of problem do you try to solve? Better is to have them in a repository manager ? (also for SNAPSHOT's)..)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Artifact paths in Maven repository will follow the following formula by default:

- `groupId` is broken into folders using the full stops as delimiter, then `artifactId` and `version` form the last two folders
- filename of the artifact consists of `artifactId` and `version`, type is defined by `packaging`

So, let's say you have a multi-module project with main `pom.xml`:

```
<groupId>com.foobar.my.business</group>
<artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
```

And it has two submodules, first is web module that creates a REST endpoint:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.foobar.my.business</group>
  <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>myApp-web</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

Second one is persistence layer:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>com.foobar.my.business</group>
  <artifactId>myApp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>myApp-persistence</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Let's say your local repository is found from `~/.m2/repository`. Then your artifacts will be saved in local repository at:

- ~/.m2/repository/com/foobar/my/business/myapp/1.0-SNAPSHOT/myapp-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
- ~/.m2/repository/com/foobar/my/business/myapp-web/1.0-SNAPSHOT/myapp-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
- ~/.m2/repository/com/foobar/my/business/myapp-web/1.0-SNAPSHOT/myapp-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
- ~/.m2/repository/com/foobar/my/business/myapp-persistence/1.0-SNAPSHOT/myapp-persistence-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
- ~/.m2/repository/com/foobar/my/business/myapp-persistence/1.0-SNAPSHOT/myapp-persistence-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar

An artifact's final build name and the local repository location can be tinkered with. But you can use the following expressions to check those:

- `${settings.localRepository}` will return path to local repository.
- `${project.build.finalName}` will return final build artifact name.

To get this list in almost the correct format, you can run:

- On Windows `mvn -q exec:exec -Dexec.executable="cmd" -Dexec.args="/C echo ${settings.localRepository}\${project.groupId}\${project.artifactId}\${project.version}\${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}"`
- On POSIX `mvn -q exec:exec -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${settings.localRepository}/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}'`

Then you just have to fix the full stops in `groupId`.

There is also a `mvn dependency:build-classpath` command which will show the location of each dependency on the file system that can come in handy sometimes.

Comment: I think `${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}` is actually all I need.  We have a CI/CD server that must persist artifacts into long-term storage.  That will let me know the right name of the file to target.

Comment: Ok, well your question is asking for paths, which generally means something more than just filename. But long as the answer helps. :)

Comment: yeah sorry, by "path" i meant the build directory path (defaults to target, but can be changed) as well as the tfile name.  So using your guidance I  am spitting out
`mvn -q exec:exec -Dexec.executable='echo' -Dexec.args='${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}'`